# Why I can't use string by index from array?

Tags: matlab

I'm new in Matlab, can somebody tell me, why I can't use a string by index like this?

```
adresuSarasas = {
"C:\\ExperimentData\\volunteer01.txt",
"C:\\ExperimentData\\volunteer02.txt",
"C:\\ExperimentData\\volunteer03.txt",
"C:\\ExperimentData\\volunteer04.txt",
"C:\\ExperimentData\\volunteer05.txt",
"C:\\ExperimentData\\volunteer06.txt",
"C:\\ExperimentData\\volunteer07.txt",
"C:\\ExperimentData\\volunteer08.txt",
"C:\\ExperimentData\\volunteer09.txt",
"C:\\ExperimentData\\volunteer10.txt",
}



skirtukas=';';
pradzia=1;
V1=importdata(adresuSarasas(2), skirtukas, pradzia)
```

I get error on the last line.  `error: importdata: FNAME must be a string`. Thanks.

Comment: Don't make a `cell` array of `string` (double-quote strings as opposed to single quote `char` vectors). Instead, just make a vector of `string`, like this: `adresuSarasas = ["path\to\one.txt", "path\to\two.txt"];` . Then, normal `()` indexing will work as you expect and `adresuSarasas(2)` will return you a single `string`.

Comment: You don't need the double `\\` here either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cell arrays have different output when indexed differently.

`adresuSarasas(2)` returns a 1x1 cell array that contains your string, while your function expects a string, not a cell array.

`adresuSarasas{2}` returns the string inside the cell array which is what your function is expecting.

while later version of matlab have functions accept 1x1 cell arrays (so this code works on newer versions) it's still fruitful to know the difference when working with older versions.

Comment: It seems that Octave uses a language called "Octave", I thought it uses Matlab actually.